# NameVirtualHost causes 404 for localhost

Tags: apache, macos, virtualhost

I've managed to setup several VirtualHosts by enabling NameVirtualHost. Here's the top part of my vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysite.local
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is when I visit `http://localhost` I get the default "It works!". If I go to `http://127.0.0.1/` it defaults to `http://mysite.local`

I understand from the Apache Docs that why it defaults to mysite.local (matching the first VirtualHost). But I used to be able to go to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`.

How can I get this back? Do I need to make my first VirtualHost localhost? That seems wrong...

Running apache 2.2.15 on Mac OS X (10.6.6).

#### UPDATE

If I comment out the following lines from my hosts file, both localhost and 127.0.0.1 go to the same place. I verified in the access log that it was indeed using ::1.

```
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

So I suppose that handles the first issue, provided this is okay? But how can I get localhost to go to my default DocumentRoot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't mix VirtualHosts with "classic" configuration.
You could listen on another port and define another VirtualHost (*:8080 for example) "emulating" your previous "localhost" going to your general DocumentRoot declaration.

Something like this:

```
Listen 80 (already declared elsewhere)
Listen 8080
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:8080

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysite.local
  ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot /same/as/the/classic/one/
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

You could also declare some Alias /phpmyadmin/ which would be global be I don't recommend aliases because you couldn't have another phpmyadmin folder in one of your vhosts.

You can of course define a phpmyadmin.local vhost ;-)

Comment: I guess in the end I merely wanted to ensure I didn't break anything with my setup. As you said though, seems like there's no way to mix. Before I had several *utility* apps like phpmyadmin, etc, as sub directories in my general document root. So I'll just have to put those somewhere else, as localhost under another port, or create specific vhosts for each?

Comment: To me the best approach is to create one vhost per utility app. You may want to use that http://clickontyler.com/virtualhostx/ ;-)

Answer (score 3):

> > How can I get this back? Do I need to make my first VirtualHost localhost? That seems wrong...

I did it like this and all seems to be working just fine, without needing an extra port to listen on.

The first VirtualHost block 
handles any URL that doesn't point to one of the 2 vhosts (2nd and 3rd VirtualHost blocks) I have set up:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/imputation/dirmaster/http/"
    ServerName imputation.loc

    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/imputation/dirmaster/http/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/documentatiebestand/"
    ServerName documentatiebestand.loc

    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/documentatiebestand/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```